# Asp.Net MVC Culture Cookie Changes But Not UI Language Until Second Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In my Asp.Net MVC application, the users come from another system with a URL that contains their own UserId. In the initial request of the users, after the authentication process, the user's language option is synchronized to the corresponding cookie value.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult Login(Guid userId, UserType userType)
    {
        try
        {
            IAccount account = null;

            if (userType == UserType.SystemUser)
                account = _accountService.CheckSystemUser(userId);
            if (userType == UserType.Employee)
                account = _accountService.CheckEmployee(userId);

            if (account == null) throw new Exception(ErrorMessages.UserNotFound);

            var roles = account.Roles.ToArray();

            var principalModel = new CustomPrincipalViewModel
            {
                UserId = account.UserId.ToString(),
                FullName = account.FullName,
                Roles = roles,
                Language = account.Language
            };

            var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principalModel);
            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, principalModel.FullName, DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userData);
            var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            var requestCookie =Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (requestCookie != null) requestCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            var responseCookie =Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if(responseCookie != null) responseCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            SetCulture(account.Language.CultureCode);

            return Json(new {isSuccess = true, userFullName = account.FullName});

        }
        catch (BusinessExceptions.CannotConnectToCrmServiceException ex)
        {
            ElmahManager.Log(ex);
            return Json(new { isSuccess = false, errorText = ErrorMessages.GeneralError });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ElmahManager.Log(exception);
            return Json(new { isSuccess = false, errorText = ErrorMessages.GeneralError });
        }
    }

    private void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
        var requestCookie =Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (requestCookie != null) requestCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);


        var cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie == null)
        {
            cultureCookie = new HttpCookie("_culture")
            {
                Value = culture,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            cultureCookie.Value = culture;
            cultureCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cultureCookie);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
```

After this process, when I change the language selection of the user from the database and refresh the page, the page language does not change. In the meantime, when I check the cookie value, I see that it is the same as the current language value, but the page language does not change until the page is refreshed a second time.

Comment: You mean that after Login() user has default language, only after refresh you can get appropriate language?

Comment: And why would it change ? Result of Login method is json (probably triggered by AJAX) - so calling Login method which does set the culture cookie doesn't force page refresh.

Comment: You're right @MaxMokrousov

Comment: As you said Login method called by AJAX @OndrejSvejdar. How can I force to page refresh in this method ?

Comment: @Yusuf Duyar. Use ActionResult instead of JsonResult of return Login value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
public JsonResult Login(Guid userId, UserType userType)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Login(Guid userId, UserType userType)
```

and return View or Redirect.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(Guid userId, UserType userType)
{
    try{

     //Your logic 
     return View(new {isSuccess = true, userFullName = account.FullName});
    }
    catch (BusinessExceptions.CannotConnectToCrmServiceException ex)
    {
        ElmahManager.Log(ex);
        return View(new { isSuccess = false, errorText = ErrorMessages.GeneralError });
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ElmahManager.Log(exception);
        return View(new { isSuccess = false, errorText = ErrorMessages.GeneralError });
    }
}
```

Comment: My previous code was what you said. However, the customer said that they waited too long for users to log in the first time the application was opened, and that they saw a blank screen. After that I changed my code so that my code would immediately return to a view and do all other operations with ajax queries. How do you do this in a way that will keep users on the loading screen and load the page with the new language at the same time?

Comment: @Yusuf Duyar I would rather suggest you to investigate performance issue than make ajax. But if you want make ajax request than you have to call location.reload(); in callback.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :) I have changed my authentication process and return view from this action.